# ajax-login servlet: servlet does not make the answer to ajax code

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, authentication

I have a login form (name and password) and I want that when the user enters his name and password, an ajax code to execute and am calling a servlet that makes the verification and it makes the resulta (succees or failure)

here is the code for my form:

```
<form action="" method="GET" id="login_frm">
        <label ><b>Username: </b></label>
        <input class="field" type="text" id="log" value="" size="23" />
        <label ><b>Password:</b></label>
        <input class="field" type="password"  id="pwd" size="23" />
        <input type="submit"  value="" class="button_login" />
</form>
```

and here is the ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#login_frm").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/RecommandationDefault/connexion?user='+$('#log').val()+'&pwd='+$('#pwd').val(),
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
              }
          });
        });
            ........

    }
```

I simplified the processing of my servlet like fate when I click the login button, the servlet execute: out.write ("ok") and I do a ajax alert in response to verify that communication takes place.

the code of my servlet (connexion.java)

```
@WebServlet(name = "connexion")
public class connexion extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {

        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
         PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");

        out.write("ok");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Problem: the Consul appears ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
But no alert is triggered.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from servlet. Try any hardcoded value in alert instead of `msg`

```
success: function(msg){
           alert("Done");
        }
```

Comment: I did what you told me but nothing is displayed

Comment: Check net tab in firebug and check what response you are getting from servlet

Comment: in my tab net, they are not a name of my servlet connexion